# SSH refuses to work no matter how much work

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ssh, virtualbox

I am running on a Windows laptop to a Ubuntu MacBook Pro that's running Ubuntu Sever on VirtualBox. I'm running it over VM because the connection at my house is dynamic and Wi-Fi only, and I cannot change those settings as I have no control over it.

I've tried tinkering with the 00-installer YAML file a bunch, I've attempted messing with port forwarding on the VM. I've re-installed Ubuntu Server something like 4 times just to reset everything, assuming that I may have messed something up to prevent SSH from working. Can't even connect over localhost; and it goes without saying but SSH is installed on all the OS/distros.

No matter how many times I've changed things or it's just been the base install, I am fully unable to SSH into UServer, the base Ubuntu install (not VM), can't SSH into Windows, nor into a VM of Ubuntu on Windows.

Windows base:

````
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::47cf:c43f:73a:8bfb%2
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.62.195.223
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.128.128.128```
````

Ubuntu base:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:07:54:10:e4:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:cf:da:e0:ec:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.253.67.224/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 86055sec preferred_lft 86055sec
    inet6 fe80::3a30:6245:451b:b435/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.133.1/24 brd 192.168.133.255 scope global vmnet1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.98.1/24 brd 172.16.98.255 scope global vmnet8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Ubuntu Server (VM & pseudo-static + eth)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ7Qs.png

Comment: Add a NAT virtual network adapter

Comment: @mully NAT's been enabled

Comment: Okay, what error do you get when trying to connect via SSH? Is the service running? Can you ping the VM? Also, your VM is using a /24 mask and ur bases are on /8

Put your VM onto the 10.x.x.x/8

Comment: SSHing always times out, SSH is active, pinging from Windows to VM is unreachable while Ubuntu to VM filters the packet. I believe I've changed the mask to /8, though same results happen.

Comment: Whats the new address that your VM has now?

Comment: It's 10.0.2.15/8

Comment: Can you set your default gateway to the same as ur Windows PC?

Comment: It's now been set as the same, same result

Comment: Restart the SSH service after changing IPs?

Comment: It's still timing out

Comment: Can you post the results of a traceroute from your Windows PC to your VM

Comment: Tracing route to 10.0.2.15 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1  10.128.128.128  reports: Destination net unreachable.

Trace complete.

Comment: I'd say start from scratch, but instead of trying to setup SSH right away, try to get the VM able to communicate with your windows PC.

Your Ubuntu base should be on the same network as your windows PC, then when setting up the VM make sure you use a virtual NAT network adapter, then try pining your ubuntu base to your windows pc, then if that works, try pinging your VM to your windows PC.